# System identification from Bode plot

Tags: system-identification, bode

Please can anyone address me to routines (possibly for MATLAB/Octave) to identify system poles and zeros from its Bode plot (magnitude+phase)? I am aware there are functions for system identification included in the Control toolbox/package, but these seem to operate on time responses (e.g. step response) instead of Bode plots. How do they perform in terms of accuracy? Thank you.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ug/frequency-domain-identification-estimating-models-using-frequency-domain-data.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, the online Mathworks documentation you pointed me to does not give much insight on the algorithms, and, to my best knowledge, there seem to be no routines for the Octave environment. Without MATLAB and its dedicated toolbox, I guess one has to cook his own numerical recipe.

Comment: This is not overly challenging for pole/zeros separated by a decade or more given that every pole contributes -6 dB/octave of magnitude slope and -90 degrees of phase, and every zero the opposite. I use the phase for identification at the 45 degree crossings. Is it that you have closely spaced poles and zeros so have the challenge of curve fitting the solution?

Comment: Dan, data are acquired from real complex systems, so yes, poles and zeros may be closely spaced, with possibly noisy lines at high frequencies. So while it remains possible to sit down and tinker with pencils and rulers and patience, I'd rather use a function that makes it possible to render it a step of an automated analysis toolchain. I thought Octave had this facility in the Control package but either I was wrong or I'm definitely overlooking something.